# Determine what is blocking UI thread

Tags: .net, wpf, multithreading, user-interface, block

I am working on a rather large .NET WPF real-time application. The application is working great and as expected, except for one BIG issue - UI Update is slow.

This application is highly event driven, there are events raised all over for all sorts of things - through these events the UI is updated.

One or many of these events is blocking the UI from displaying immediately. When all the work is complete, the UI shows the expected results.

Is there any way of determining which event handler is causing the bottleneck?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

I fully support colithium's suggestion of using a profiler.

In addition, if the blocking takes more than a second, you might be able to hit the "Pause" button in Visual Studio. In the tool bar, there's a dropdown list where you can choose the "Main Thread". Then it jumps to the method which is currently blocking the UI.

Comment: Thank You Heinze! Tried your suggestion and it worked wonderfully. Very usefull and simple trick to remember. Believe it or not, it's the application log which was causing the issue. Using log4net appender to update a RichTextBox log UI.

Comment: You said: "In the tool bar, there's a dropdown list where you can choose the Main Thread". Do you mean you can see where the main thread was at the time you hit Pause? Or do you mean you can find out what is BLOCKING the main thread? I know there is a debug window which has a list of threads. Is that what you mean by dropdown in the toolbar? I noticed that when I pause a long operation I often hit a specific area in the code on UI thread that shuld not take long. So UI thread must be blocked on something (semaphore or what not) is there a way to see what if It's not in my code?

Answer (score 26):

```
  public class UIBlockDetector
{
    static Timer _timer;
    public UIBlockDetector(int  maxFreezeTimeInMilliseconds = 200)
    {
        var sw = new Stopwatch();

        new DispatcherTimer(TimeSpan.FromMilliseconds(10), DispatcherPriority.Send, (sender, args) =>
        {
            lock (sw)
            {
                sw.Restart();
            }

        }, Application.Current.Dispatcher);

        _timer = new Timer(state =>
        {
            lock (sw)
            {
                if (sw.ElapsedMilliseconds > maxFreezeTimeInMilliseconds)
                {
                    // Debugger.Break() or set breakpoint here;
                    // Goto Visual Studio --> Debug --> Windows --> Theads 
                    // and checkup where the MainThread is.
                }
            }

        }, null, TimeSpan.FromMilliseconds(0), TimeSpan.FromMilliseconds(10));

    }

}
```

Just new this class in MainWindow constructor. When the breakpoint hits, you can go to Visual Studio --> Debug --> Windows --> Threads and check what operation blocked your UI-Thread!

Comment: New the class at a plce of your choice + set a breakpoint inside the " if (sw.ElapsedMilliseconds > maxFreezeTimeInMilliseconds)". This class is just a watchdog logic for the mainthread.

Comment: What Timer are you using here?

Comment: Wow. That works really really great. Nice one there. I'll keep it handy.

Comment: one of the most useful snippets i have ever kept ! thanks @Andreas

Comment: @Andreas is 10 milliseconds going to cause any bottlenecks on the main thread from the DispatcherTimer? Any reason why you chose that value?

Comment: This is genius and helped me out immensely. Thankyou!

Comment: This seems to do exactly what I need, but I'm not upvoting this because of the time I had to spend figuring out the using statements that could have been easily included in the code snippet.

Answer (score 6):

Do you have access to a code profiler?  This is the type of thing they are good at.  I recommend obtaining one if the answer is no.

Besides using a profiler.  You can do "poor man's" profiling by placing timing statements at the beginning and end of code blocks that you suspect.  You can even use a breakpoints and time it with a wall clock.  Does the issue happen when you click something?  If so start there.  Is it a recurring issue without user interaction?  Start with timers then.

As for actually solving the problem...  Unless the offending handler is doing something that can be made more efficient, consider adopting a multi-threaded approach.  The new Task library for .NET 4.0 is really amazing in this regard.

Comment: Hi Colithium. Thanks for responding. The application is multithreaded - making use of Parallelism in my Linq queries and loops. In addition, instead of working with Thread objects i am using the Task.Factory.StartNew for multi-threading. The application contains no timers nor any backgroundworkers. I have a main non-blocking Task (thread) which contains only business logic, i.e. no UI interaction at all. The logic in this task takes certain actions and raises events associated with those actions. I am using VS2010 - which has a profiler. Don't know how to use it and how to assess the results.

Answer (score 0):

As a first order approxximation, I find it useful to break in the debugger (with the pause button in the IDE), and look at the stack. Do this a few times, and you can see if there is a pattern. Are you always in the same function? Are you doing something expensive in response to an event? Are you getting more events that you expect?  It's low tech, but can be very effective.