# Automatically show loader on long operation

Tags: c#, wpf

I'm trying to show a loader animation when my application it's blocked for more than 500ms.
I want that to be automatic, I don't want to add any piece of code before every long operation.

I know that in WinForms it was possible (I used this: https://snipplr.com/view/24851/), but It does not work in WPF.
I've found that I can do that with the mouse cursor([display Hourglass when application is busy](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3480966/display-hourglass-when-application-is-busy))

I've tried to launch a window with a spinner.
I've found this answer (https://stackoverflow.com/a/21411656/10820863), that works detecting long operation. 
Problem is that if I launch a window from a thread that is not the main one, I got a `ThreadException` because it's not the main thread. If I use `Application.Current.Dispatcher.BeginInvoke`
 method, the window appears only when UI is not blocked anymore.

So, how can I automatically detect long operation and show a loading window/page/image/whatever if it lasts for more than 500ms?

[EDIT]
I don't want to add code to every long function, evaluating case for case which function can be long. 
I'd prefer to have an automatic method that do that for me.

Comment: The problem lies more in the way you wrote your application: executing long-running code in the UI thread. So the fix is obvious but not simple: rewrite parts of your application to execute long-running code using tasks or a background thread.

Comment: Unfortunately this is very complex. There are a lot of long operations with UI interaction (and I think there will be lot of problem with threads).